# Entity Framework in child project not reading connectionstring sent to it

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have created a separate Entity Framework project (with .NET 6) to be used with many different solutions. However, when I use it as a child project, it won't read the connection strings sent to it.

Here's what I mean: let's say the projects are called `UserProject` and `EFProject`.

`EFProject` is a class library which includes a `DBContext` and all the models representing the database.

It includes this class:

```
public partial class MyDataContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDataContext()
    {
    }

    public MyDataContext (DbContextOptions<MyDataContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("test database connectionstring");
}
```

In my main project, `UserProject`, I have added this to `appsettings.json`:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
   "UseThisConnectionString": "production connectionstring"
}
```

and in `Program.cs` I have added:

```
 builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDataContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("UseThisConnectionString"))
            , ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
```

However, no matter what I try, the `EFProject` keeps using the test database connection string and not reading the connection string I send to it in the main project. It is like these two projects are not in talking terms about this.

How do I relay the proper connection string to the child project?

Comment: And how your context is instantiated?

Comment: The connection string in OnConfiguring method is always going to take precedence because it's the first method that gets called.

To resolve this issue, you need to remove the hardcoded connection string from the OnConfiguring method in the MyDataContext class and only use the connection string that you pass via the AddDbContext method in your main project.

Comment: @VadimMartynov I gave this one a go, but then I'll get an error saying no Connection string is set, no matter if AddDbContext is used in the UserProject or not

Answer (score 1):

One approach is trying to check [`DbContextOptionsBuilder.IsConfigured`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder.isconfigured?view=efcore-7.0) property:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if(!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured) 
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("test database connectionstring");
}
```

Otherwise options will always be overridden (also possibly you can just remove the `OnConfiguring` override completely).

P.S.

In my personal experience I highly recommend against registering EF database context as `ServiceLifetime.Singleton`.

Comment: I tried this but on the EFProject DbContextOptionsBuilder.IsConfigured is always false, no matter if the dbcontext is set in the UserProject or not

Comment: @marginaalivirhe how the context is instantiated? Try removing parameterless ctor, are there any compilation errors?